# MySQL select first SUB-ID of MAIN-ID

Tags: mysql

My MySQL Table save for an **MainID (kartikelpict)** more than one entries. Each entry of that has again another **SubID (nNr)**. How can I select the lowest SubID?

```
+--------------+--------------+-------+
| kartikelpict |     cPfad    |  nNr  |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
|     560      | picture4.jpg |   4   |
|     560      | picture3.jpg |   3   |
|     560      | picture2.jpg |   2   |
|     560      | picture.jpg  |   1   |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
```

My SQL request is like below combined with another table

```
SELECT 
p1.kArtikel, 
p1.cName, 
p1.cKurzBeschreibung, 
p1.dLetzteAktualisierung, 
p1.dErstellt, 
p1.cSeo,
p2.kartikelpict,
p2.nNr,
p2.cPfad

FROM tartikel AS p1, tartikelpict AS p2 
WHERE p1.kArtikel = p2.kartikelpict 
ORDER BY kArtikel 
DESC LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join on your `tartikelpict` by getting the minimum amount of `nNr`

```
SELECT 
p1.kArtikel, 
p1.cName, 
p1.cKurzBeschreibung, 
p1.dLetzteAktualisierung, 
p1.dErstellt, 
p1.cSeo,
p2.kartikelpict,
p2.nNr,
p2.cPfad
FROM tartikel AS p1
JOIN tartikelpict AS p2 
ON(p1.kArtikel = p2.kartikelpict )
JOIN (SELECT kartikelpict ,MIN(nNr) nNr 
FROM tartikelpict GROUP BY kartikelpict ) p3
ON(p2.kartikelpict = p3.kartikelpict AND p2.nNr =p3.nNr)
ORDER BY p1.kArtikel 
DESC LIMIT 50
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0facd/1)

Comment: Your Code is buggy? `FROM tartikelpict GROUP BY kartikelpict ) p3`

Comment: @karadayi see my updated answer when i first posted there was some typos see now

Comment: @karadayi can you post sample data set [*@sql fiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with above query ?

Comment: Hey Khalid, Interesting but the call is correct.. Maybe I am calling it wrong on my DOM Element `$data = $xml->createElement('guid', $rssdata["nNr"]);` [The SQL FIDDLE sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dcdf/1)

Comment: @karadayi see [**second demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0facd/1) i have added more data to test and for 561 the picture4.jpg has the minimum nNr ,may be the way you are doing it with dom is confusing

Comment: Your Code is correct! Thank you very much but seems that my DOM has an Error

Comment: I suggest you to ask question to your dom related problem with specific tags like php, ..

Comment: I will create a new Question for that or should I do it here?

Comment: @karadayi now you should ask new one becuse this one relates to mysql and your problem relates to php

Comment: I have to wait 90 Minutes to post anything new :)